# DropDownlist compare validator issue

Tags: asp.net

I am validating the drop down list, if drop down list has value 'Select' then it should show error message else not.

This is my code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGender" ValidationGroup="ben" runat="server" Width="200px" CssClass="ap-main">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="cv1" ValidationGroup="ben" ControlToValidate="ddlGender" runat="server"
                              ValueToCompare="Select" Operator="NotEqual" ErrorMessage="Please select Gender." Type="String"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

This not working.

what's wrong in it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is Value of first item in dropdown is "Select"?check it first...

Comment: sorry its my mistake, in ValueTocompare i was giving text not value. value is 0 so its now working.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a validator to check if something was selected then rather use a [RequiredField validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbw267h%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and use the setting called `InitialValue="Select"`

Answer (score 0):

you can try on server side that..

```
if(ddlGender.SelectedValue=="Select")
 {
 //error message..
 }
```

or

```
   if(ddlGender.SelectedText=="Select")
     {
    //error message
     }
```

when you load that dropdownlist or onselectedindexchanged event..